# Connect to Postgres running on the Windows host from WSL2

Tags: windows, postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am trying to connect to PostgreSQL DB installed on my windows machine from WSL2 however facing issues while connecting would appreciate if you can help me resolve this issue. In addition to that I have tried below options already.

1. Windows postgreSQL is running fine on port `5432`
2. Have below entry in `pg_hba.conf` file

   ```
   host     all            all             0.0.0.0/0                md5
   ```
3. Checked windows IP address for WSL2 from following command and then
   Telnet , still no luck

   ```
   sudo cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{ print $2 }' 
   172.19.240.1
   telnet 172.19.240.1 5432
   ```
4. Defined inbound firewall rule for port 5432 from **Windows Defender
   Firewall with Advanced Security** Still not working
5. Disabled firewall completely - same issue :(

OS : Windows 10 Home

Error Message

```
Trying 172.19.240.1...
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: its always showing Trying 172.19.240.1...

Comment: That is a network message. Either your routing table is messed up, or you forgot a firewall somewhere.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Any pointer how can i debugit

Comment: That is a networking problem and off-topic here. Sorry, but I don't know enough about networking.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe , no Worries. I will try something from my end :)